# Escribir XLS con Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, xls

Quiero leer y escribir archivos XLS utilizando Apache POI pero a la hora de escribir me estoy topando con bastantes problemas,

```
public static void escribirXLS(Licencia licencia, String fichero) {
        
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
        
        int rowCount = 0;
        
        Row row = sheet.createRow(++rowCount);
        
        crearLicencia(licencia, row);
        
        try {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fichero, true); //Si pongo false me borra todo y escribe todo 1 celda desplazado a la derecha
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(fichero));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Licencia es un objeto en el que guardo los datos

Para escribir en las celdas uso el metodo `crearLicencia()`

```
private static void crearLicencia(Licencia licencia, Row row) {
        
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getAno());
        
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getTipoLicencia());
        
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getLicencia());
        
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getAnosVigente());
        
        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getModoEmision());
        
        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getTipoTitular());
        
        cell = row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getTitularNacionalidad());
        
        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getTitularProvincia());
        
        cell = row.createCell(8);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getTitularMunicipio());
        
        cell = row.createCell(9);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getTitularNacimiento());
        
        cell = row.createCell(10);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getImporte());
        
        cell = row.createCell(11);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getFechaSolicitud());
        
        cell = row.createCell(12);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getFechaValidez());
        
        cell = row.createCell(13);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getIdLicencia());
        
        cell = row.createCell(14);
        cell.setCellValue(licencia.getTipoLicencia());

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Con qué problemas te estás topando?

Comment: Ah pensé que lo había puesto, perdón, cuando pongo el `FileOutputStream` en true no escribe nada, cuando no pongo nada borra todo y escribe el la primera fila 1 celda desplazado hacia la derecha

Comment: Intenta  try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fichero, true) ) { .... 
Eso asegura que se cierra el outputstream